# Estimate/inequality releated to the Hausdorff measure

Tags: measure-theory, fractals, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Define the diameter of a subset $Y \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ of the metric space $(\mathbb R^n, d)$ with the standard metric $d$ to be

$$\operatorname{diam}(Y) := \sup_{\mathbf x,\mathbf y \in Y} d(\mathbf x, \mathbf y).$$

Now define the ball $B_r(\mathbf y) := \{ \mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n : d(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) \leq r\}$ and consider the ball

$A := B_r(\mathbf 0)$ and a cover $\{A_k\}_{k\geq 1} \supset A$, which don't have to be optimal (a cover here only need to satisfy $A\subset \bigcup_{k\geq 1} A_k$).

The actual claim we proved in class was that the (outer) Hausdorff $n$-dimensional measure (here: $n\in\mathbb N$) is defined on the same $\sigma$-algebra as the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, and that they agreed up to a constant $C(n)$ depending on $n$.

Doing so, we used the inequality

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq 1} \operatorname{diam}(A_k)^n \geq (2r)^n$$

valid *for any* cover $\{A_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ to $A$ satisfying

$$\operatorname{diam}(A_k) < 2r \; \; \forall k$$

How can one prove this inequality?

Comment: Can't you just use that $|A_k| \le c_n \text{diam}(A_k)^n$, where $c_n$ is s.t. $|A| = c_n (2r)^n$?

Comment: @mathworker21 What do you mean by |A| here?

Comment: Lebesgue measure of $A$